Account sync - Calendar and Google Calendar toggles
When I go to add a new Google Workspace account (not created by me) in Android, I get a view showing toggles for "Calendar" and "Google Calendar".

I use Google Calendar but I can't tell what "Calendar" refers to.
I'm on a Pixel 8 and have not installed any other calendar apps. When I search app drawer, Google Play Store installed apps, and Settings > Apps, only Google Calendar shows.
Note that I found a similar question here - What is the difference between Calendar and Google Calendar in Account sync settings - but it's for an outdated device, has no answer, and the device there ships with its own non-Google Calendar app (which of course a Pixel would not).

It just occurred to me that the "Calendar" toggle may refer to some sort of weird import from my last phone's "tap" sync (from the Pixel's near-device install sync) that brought over Samsung's Galaxy Calendar info somehow that's now confusing Android's account sync feature.
Anyway, I wouldn't know what to do about that anyway besides completely reformatting the phone and not doing a device sync again. I'm not sure what I would try in that case other than just relying on the Google account backups.

I don't think that's the case. I just checked my Pixel 8, which was recently set up with import from 6a. Aside, in my case, I don't see toggles to enable/disable sync for all components.. weird

Speculative reason

Logical explanation which you may need to verify
